# How to run Weavy Server in a docker container?

Tags: docker, weavy

How to run Weavy Server in a docker container?

https://github.com/weavy/weavy-server

Answer (score 1):

Running Weavy in a Docker container is currently not supported. You could probably create your own Docker image and make it work, but it's not officially supported.

Answer (score -1):

/weavy-server

1. Pull the docker container:
   docker pull dockerweavy/weavy-server
2. Create a directory to store your Weavy Server configuration and data:
   mkdir -p /path/to/weavyserverdata
3. Run the container, mapping the configuration and data directory to a folder on your host machine:
   docker run -d --name weavyserver -v /path/to/weavyserverdata:/opt/weavy-server -p 8080:8080 dockerweavy/weavy-server
4. Once the container is running, you can access the Weavy Server web interface at http://localhost:8080.